# How do you tell if your application tile is pinned to the start screen?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

In a Universal app how can you tell if your application has been pinned to the start screen?
I can see you can query the secondary tiles like this

```
SecondaryTile.FindAllAsync()
```

But I can't find anything similar for the primary tile.

(The reason I want to do this is to unregister for live tile updates if my app is no longer on the start screen)

Comment: Why the down vote? Please tell me what you think is wrong with this question so I can improve it.

Comment: Not, specifically, this use case, but Microsoft *used* to provide such APIs for similar features in Windows. And then they found that some developers will nag the user if the user isn't enlightened enough to know that **this** application is so special that it should always be pinned/always show its notification icon, etc. So these days, Microsoft don't tend to expose such APIs. It's those other developers who mean that we don't get nice things.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, annoying though when you're just trying to be efficient and only use data when there is something to show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for now it is impossible to detect if tile pinned to start page, but for your purpose you can use this:

`NotificationSetting ns = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Setting;`

List of possible values for NotificationSetting variable `ns` can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.notifications.notificationsetting.aspx).

I've checked this behavior. When tile was pinned - the value was `Enabled`, when I unpinned the tile - setting became `DisabledForApplication`. So you could assume that tile does not need updates if it is not in `Enabled` state.

Also you can review [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148) provided by Microsoft for more details.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Interesting, you get Enabled by default but if you pin and unpin the application it then flips to DisabledForApplication. This is probably close enough for me so I'll accept this until someone comes up with a better solution (if one exists). Thanks for the answer